# Oracle xlmtype how to extract

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I know there were a lot of questions about it but I did not manage to solve problem on my example. I have xlmtype column in my oracle database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationProductFields>
  <string>
<field name="A">aaa</field>
<field name="B">bbb</field>
<field name="C">ccc</field>
<field name="D">ddd</field>
 </string>
 <int>
<field name="E">1</field>
<field name="F">2</field>
</int>
</ApplicationProductFields>
```

How to convert it by query to conventional data like this:

```
FIELD_NAME      VALUE
A                aaa
B                bbb
C                ccc
D                ddd
E                1
F                2
```

Oracle does not allow to use names like string or field name in query

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
WITH test
     AS (SELECT xmltype ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationProductFields>
  <string>
<field name="A">aaa</field>
<field name="B">bbb</field>
<field name="C">ccc</field>
<field name="D">ddd</field>
 </string>
 <int>
<field name="E">1</field>
<field name="F">2</field>
</int>
</ApplicationProductFields>') data
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), 'field/@name') FIELD_NAME,
       EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), 'field') VALUE
  FROM test,
       TABLE (
          XMLSEQUENCE (
             EXTRACT (test.data, '/ApplicationProductFields/*/field'))) x;
```

I would suggest to spend a few days and read the [documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/toc.htm) to see what each of the above functions do, and learn XPath syntax.